# Improving SQL Query to check condition

Tags: sql, sql-server

Currently, the sql code that I have is to check for the three fee_code records do any of them have election_code = NA.

I'm trying to figure out how to change the code to check that all of the 3 records have election_code = NA.

Original Query:

```
    DECLARE @fee_code1 tinyint = 1
            ,@fee_code2 tinyint = 2
            ,@fee_code3 tinyint = 3
            ,@election_code tinyint = 0

    IF EXISTS(SELECT *
              FROM Product
              WHERE 
                product_id = @product_id
                AND fee_code in (@fee_code1, @fee_code2, @fee_code3)
                AND election_code = @election_code)
```

The solution I have is to do a count check, but I know count has a performance impact and there's probably a better way to do it.  What's a better way to do it?

Count solution:

```
    IF ((SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM Product
        WHERE 
        product_id = @product_id
        AND fee_code in (@fee_code1, @fee_code2, @fee_code3)
        AND election_code = @election_code) = 3)
```

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results to clarify your question.

Comment: "I know count has a performance impact" - does it? Have you measured it? With SQL you are best off building your solution in the most logical manner and then dealing with performance issues if you end up having any. SQL Server is pretty good at performing well so you certainly don't want to restrict your options in advance.

Comment: So to check for all records you think count is fine? I was thinking there might be a different way to check for all 3 records to have election as NA.

Comment: There is no better way to count records than using the built-in COUNT function, what do mean?

Comment: It all depends on your indexes... the first question is, does it work as you want? If you suspect a performance issue, then inspect the execution plan and see how well its running.

Comment: Works as expected. Thanks!

Comment: I must wonder about a table named "Product" where column "product_id" is not unique. Seems you likely have normalization issues as well.